# Why is the processing time the same for 2 and 4 cores and different partitions in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, parallel-processing, spark-streaming

I'm trying to run some tests regarding processing times for a Spark Streaming Application, in local mode in my 4 core machine.

Here is my code:

```
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("sparkstreaminggetjson");

    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));


    JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> streamData1 = ssc.socketTextStream(args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]),
            StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);

    streamData1.print();
```

I am receiving 1 JSON message per second.
 So, I test this for 4 different  scenerios:

1) `setMaster(...local[2])` and 1 partition

2) `setMaster(...local[*])` and 1 partition

3)`setMaster(...local[2])` and 4 partitions (using `streamData1.repartition(4)`)

4) `setMaster(...local[*])` and 4 partitions (using `streamData1.repartition(4)`)

When I check the average processing times in the UI, this is what I get for each scenario:

1) 30 ms

2) 28 ms

3) 72 ms

4) 75 ms

My question is: why are the processing times pretty much the same for 1 and 2, and 3 and 4? 
I realize that the increase from 2 to 4 for example is normal, because repartition is a shuffle operation. What I don't get is, for example in 4), why is the processing so similar to 3? Shouldn't it be much smaller since I am increasing the level of paralelization, and I have more cores to distribute the tasks to?

Hope I wasn't confusing,
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: How long is your test? How many test files did your read?  i.e. did you consider the time needed for the cluster to be configured?

Comment: @GameOfThrows, since I am working on local mode as I said before, there is no cluster to be configured, just local cores from my pc. I tested it for about two minutes, time at which I had read 120 data points (JSON messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of this depends on what your JSON message looks like, I'll assume each message is a single string without line breaks. In that case, with 1 message per second and batch interval of 1 second, at each batch you will get an RDD with just a single item. You can't split that up into multiple partitions, so when you repartition you still have the same situation data-wise, but with the overhead of the repartition step.

Even with larger amounts of data I would not expect too much of difference when all you do to the data is `print()` it: this will take the first 10 items of your data, which if they can come from just one partition, I would expect Spark to optimize that to only calculate that one partition. In any case you will get more representative numbers if you significantly increase the amount of data per batch, and do some actual processing on the whole set, at minimum something like `streamData1.count().print()`.

To get a better understanding of what happens, it is also useful to dig into the other parts of Spark's UI, like the Stages tab that can tell you how much of the execution time is shuffling, serialization, etc rather than actual execution, and things that affect performance like DAGs that tell you which bits may be cached, and tasks that Spark was able to skip.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it definitely makes sense. I tried implementing what you said, with 5 inputs per second and a  `streamData1.count().print()`. The difference between local[2] and local[*] was negligible, 65 and 62 ms respectively. But I will increase the programs complexity and number of inputs more to see if I get different results.